# Is there any website to use ubuntu operating system online?

Tags: ubuntu-website

My computer is not good enough to handle two operating system in the same time.I tried to use ubuntu on usb but it did not work and I tried to use ubuntu from virtual machine and i get the same result ? Here is my question : Is there any website to use ubuntu operating system online ? I need to do my homework on it also i must learn some basic terminology about ubuntu thanks

Comment: dual boot is always an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking to run a unix terminal from windows and not a full fledged OS, you can try something like MobaXterm, which lets you run an Xterm on Windows, giving you the same commands as you'd get from bash/cygwin.

In terms of booting ubuntu from a USB, that should work fine, provided your USB is big enough. Ubuntu itself is a pretty light OS, so it should be fine to run on any PC that can also run Windows. If booting from an Ubuntu flash drive, you may have to open up the boot menu when starting to select the flash drive as the source for the OS.

What virtual machine software did you try? I find VMWare Player can be run with fairly low system requirements to load and run an ubuntu OS image.

What are you system requirements and objectives?

If performance and system requirements are really an issue, you can take a look at `lubuntu` which is a lightweight version of ubuntu. You can even try that with a dual boot, usb boot, or VMWare Player image.

Thanks.

Comment: VMWare solved my issue.Thank you so much for your advice.